# C# - WCF - Generics - [KnownType(typeof(xxx))]

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

My client has 10 tables that it needs to load via an internal WCF to a server. Since all this is internal, I can write both client and server using whatever technique i want.

On the Client, I thought to use LINQ to load data from the tables to a List, List and so on...

On the Server, I thought to have a **[DataContract]** as follow:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Table1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Table2))]
[KnownType(typeof(Table3))]
public class GenericType<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then add the classes that will represent the matching Tables on the Client.

```
[DataContract]
public class Table1
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Table2
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Table3
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I create the client reference, i'm NOT getting all the classes declared on the server and it seems that ONLY the 1st [KnownType] specified on the [DataContract] becomes visible to the Client.

I was under the impression that **Generics was meant to allow multiple types** but **am I right to think that WCF can only handle one [KnownType] x class** ??

And if so, my only way to code this would be to **copy and paste 10 times the GenericType class and on each copy, change the [KnownType]** ??

Cause if that's the only solution, then what are the real benefits to use Generic instead of straight defined List, List for my params ??

Any thought will help clarify my mind here

---

The problem happens because unless ONE of the WCF methods uses any of the CLASSES declared as [DataContract] ...it seems that WCF does NOT brings those classes to the Client.

Is this the expected case?

Comment: "I'm getting an error". What's the exact error? Also the KnownTypes "Table1", "Table2", etc. also need to be marked with [DataContract] and[DataMember].

Comment: I thnik you are wrong you can check this on msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Comment: @Erniel even when I put the [DataContract] and [DataMember] i am still only getting Table1 on the client.

Comment: @PranayRana I read that link but still I'm getting only the first declared Type, not the others...

Answer (score 1):

You could try attributing your interface method with the [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute for each of the classes.

There is another option, which is to implement the generic lists in classes that are attributed with CollectionDataContract:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class Table1Collection
   Inherits List<Table1>
```

On the client side, you can the edit Reference.svcmap and enumerate each of the collections in the CollectionMappings section:

```
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="My.Namespace.Table1Collection" Category="List" />
```

This allows you to reuse the same code on both ends of the pipe.

Comment: If I implement that [CollectionDataContract], does that mean that I have to create 10 different classes each one pointing to a different table? If so, where is the benefit instead of having 10 classes that directly implement List<Table1> ...and so on?

Comment: You would only accrue a benefit from this approach if you had business logic within the collection classes and wanted to reuse this logic in both the client and the server.

Comment: @Developer: regarding one of the wcf methods using the class: I think that this will be resolved if you use the ServiceKnownType attribute that I mentioned in my answer.